# Highlight other similar tags in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tags, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to highlight similar words or tags when I click on one?

I thought this was possible and in the preferences I see an option, but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: For which editor (java, html, text-editor) you want highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

All right, I found it myself.

But in order to help you guys, take a look at:

**Window>Preferences** and **search** for '***Mark Occurrences***'.

Make sure these checkboxes (on the right) are checked.

---

Extra: on the ***annotations*** page you can configure colors.

Answer (score 0):

The faster and easier way to show/hide occurrences of your code is by pressing the hotkeys:

***Alt + Shift + O***